# Database error when user logs in

Tags: plugins, database, migration, permissions

We just moved our database to new server... Everything is working good..

But when the user logs in we gen an error of database...

This is how it looks

[image]

and this is the error after user logs in and now boxes are displayed.

[image]

I read that this could happens due to permission to files..

Any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure you exported ALL tables (looks like you had custom tables in there) correctly when moving to the new server. Also make sure the user that the files run on the new server are the one the web server runs on ( usually www-data )

Comment: @bynicolas i exported ALL tables, i thought that was the problem and export these one by one(import one by one as well) and there no www to previous one... Thats why it drives me crazy

Comment: and did you check the permission on the files? if your web user is `www-data` and your site is located at `/var/www/html` then change user for all subfile like so `chown -R www-data: /var/www/html`

Comment: use "duplicator" plugin, best tool for moving installations.. believe me :)